# Pop-up text field does not appear when running Python with built-in input function on Jupyter notebook

Tags: input, jupyter-notebook

Like the title, I'd like to run a python file in the same directory on Jupiter's laptop. Other actions in the python file worked meaningfully, but I came to the input() field in the python file and the text input pop-up field didn't come out, so I was stuck and waited. Examples are as follows.

```
# test.py

txt = input("input text")
print(txt)
```

```
# test.ipynb

!python test.py

#result
input text
```

Please give me good suggestions from the masters.

Comment: Is "Jupiter's laptop" the  god of the sky and thunder's laptop? Not sure why you'd be running on Jove's laptop, or why we'd even need to know whose laptop, but accepting that, it is possible if you use features in IPython/Jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your notebook, which you've named `test.ipynb`, the line invoking your script, should be the following:

```py
%run test.py
```

It will work now.
Then when you are done entering your test in the input box, hit 'Return'.

Why does it now work?

The `%run` magic Jupyter inherits from IPython is described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). It adds more features and better handles output and integrating with Jupyter for running Python scripts, as you now have seen.  **And that is a big part of why you almost never will use `!python <my_script>.py` inside a notebook.**

To understand some of what it adds and how `!python <my_script>.py` can be inadequate, your example is very good in fact. You saw it fail to work that way. And that is because the exclamation point signals to Jupyter/IPython to open a temporary, **separate** shell session and run the shell commands after it,returning the stdout. So the stdoout from over in that separate session gets returned, in your case, the '`input text`' prompt but you cannot enter text because you don't have access to that temporary session and so it just hangs there waiting for you to enter, which you cannot.

---

#### How to use additional abilities provided by `%run` magic

Under the 'Options' heading below [`%run`'s entry in the IPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) are listed some commmand line flags you can optionally use. One of them is the `i` flag, standing for for 'interactive'.

You can set variables in the notebook and use them in the script in an interactive manner if you wanted by adding the `-i` flag so that the python script gets run in the same kernel as the notebook and thus has those settings for the variables. This ability is nice for developing a script, especially if it involves complex output, or for allowing for an alternative interface for users to set things up before running a lot of code that you don't want to clutter up the notebook with.
Your example doesn't have that so let me demonstrate with an adaptation of your provided code.
Change the notebook and associated script like so:

**Notebook code**:

```py
x = "the"
%run -i test.py
```

**Script code:**

```py
txt = input(f"input {x} text")
print(txt)
```

What happens when you run the notebook cell now:
Now you see 'input the text' to the left side of the cell when you'll enter the text.

If you do **not** add the `-i` flag to the `%run` command, you'll see this error:

```py
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

The script doesn't know what `x` is because it is running separate from the Python that was running in the notebook and so it expects x to have been defined already when it comes to the `print()` line.